# Match filename with url

Tags: cypress

I am a beginner with cypress and i am trying to create a test that matches the url with linked files. n the url is a part "/en/" and the *.*pdf file should therefore contain "EN". is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Regex for this instance would be good.

```js
cy.url().should('match',/\/en\/.+.pdf/)
```

Alternatively, you don't need the entire url to check when the pathname should suffice.

```js
cy.location('pathname').should('match',/\/en\/.+.pdf/)
```